# Кодировка email письма

Tags: email, spamassasin

Не могу понять почему русские символы в кодировке. Причем в почте вид читабельный а в логах символы. Из за них в спам почта валится. Подскажите что делаю не так?

```
Return-Path: <admin@geheime-nachrichten.com>
Received: from mx2.mail.rambler.ru ([10.5.5.12] verified)
  by mail1003.rambler.ru (RamblerMail 6.1 SMTP 6.1a7)
  with ESMTP id 72511278 for 100kk@rambler.ru; Sun, 25 Mar 2018 00:53:03 +0300
Received: from geheime-nachrichten.com (geheime-nachrichten.com [176.114.6.143])
    by mx2.mail.rambler.ru (Postfix) with ESMTP id 1A7105402E1
    for <100kk@rambler.ru>; Sun, 25 Mar 2018 00:53:03 +0300 (MSK)
Received: from geheime-nachrichten.com (geheime-nachrichten.com [176.114.6.143])
    by resmtp1.mail.rambler.ru (resmtp/Rambler) with ESMTP id q33WBIYp;
    Sun, 25 Mar 2018 00:52:43 +0300
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=geheime-nachrichten.com; s=mail; h=Date:Message-Id:Cc:From:MIME-Version:
    Content-Type:Subject:To; bh=omeN4lUL9yma2A5I1MmdYFD6ESRIO0Vjs01M0PRObTM=; b=Q
    l101oKeAZ1QEf6JckD2LGSoeIYZwipFYbQ2+8yOq9QwDe7sDlQYJ+FD5YX6oORd+5suIlX/4NAcRG
    /HYPOPwFs/733zyTZZ4PY11XVhRfTOFy8O42BC2qVuXZuOSJPeSclrIukFHaDVJATcBZu/tPYsWRP
    66uXMqwP740OXInE=;
Received: from admin by geheime-nachrichten.com with local (Exim 4.86_2)
    (envelope-from <admin@geheime-nachrichten.com>)
    id 1ezr42-0002lF-SK; Sat, 24 Mar 2018 23:51:02 +0200
To: 100kk@rambler.ru
Subject: Р”РѕСЃС‚Р°РІРєР° РїРёС†С†С‹ РІ РІР°С€РµРј РіРѕСЂРѕРґРµ
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:Mail.php
Content-Type: text/plain; Charset=utf-8
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Stefan Ernst <s.ernst@geheime-nachrichten.com>
Cc: s.ernst@geheime-nachrichten.com
Message-Id: <E1ezr42-0002lF-SK@geheime-nachrichten.com>
Date: Sat, 24 Mar 2018 23:51:02 +0200
X-Spam: yes

Р”РѕР±СЂС‹Р№ РґРµРЅСЊ. РќР°С€Р° РєРѕРјРїР°РЅРёСЏ РѕСЃСѓС‰РµСЃС‚РІР»СЏРµС‚ РґРѕСЃС‚РІРєСѓ РїРёС†С†С‹ РІ РІР°С€РµРј РіРѕСЂРѕРґРµ. РќР°С€Р° РїРёС†С†Р° Р»СѓС‡С€Р°СЏ РІ СЃС‚СЂР°РЅРµ! РћР±СЂР°С‰Р°Р№С‚РµСЃСЊ РїРѕ СЃР»РµРґСѓСЋС‰РёРј С‚РµР»РµС„РѕРЅР°Рј 0800 80 50 60.
```

Это в коде:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; Charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Stefan Ernst <".$this::FROM.">\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: ".$this::FROM."\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: ".$this::FROM."\r\n";
```

HTML в письмах не планирую использовать.

Comment: Как минимум по техническим причинам желательно всё-всё-всё экранировать, чтобы не-ASCII символов не было вообще. Вот, например, собранное мною письмо, вполне русское, на спам вроде никто не жаловался (хотя конкретно spamassasin не проверял) и даже HTML имеется: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jbVKFpMQTv/

Comment: @andreymal что то не понял что вы имеете ввиду( Что экранировать?

Comment: Откройте письмо по моей ссылке да посмотрите, base64 например

Comment: А экранировать нужно всё что не английское